# Evaluating the Gamma Function with Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

So, I recently discovered the gamma function, and I was playing around with this variant of it:
$$\int_0^\infty{x^z e^{-x}}dx$$
It appears to be impossible to take the antiderivative of this. I looked around, and all I could find were answers for special cases and certain numbers. But for any number "z", how would you perform this integration?
The best thing I could think of was creating a taylor series for
$$x^z e^{-x}$$
and then integrating that. Would that work, or is there another method I'm missing?
(Sorry, calculus noob here.)
Thanks!

Comment: You could use recursion.

Comment: If $z$ is an integer, integrate by parts $z$ times.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the responses - In the end, I decided to use a riemann sum.

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember this formula?
$$ \int a^xdx=\frac{1}{\ln a}a^x+C $$
So
$$ \int x^zdz=\int e^{z\ln x}dz=\frac{1}{\ln x}x^z+C $$
and hence
$$ \int \Gamma(z)dz=\int\int_0^\infty x^ze^{-x}dxdz=\int_0^\infty\int x^ze^{-x}dzdx=\int_0^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{\ln x}x^z+C\bigg)e^{-x}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\ln x}x^ze^{-x}dx+C. $$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer - I decided to use a Riemann Sum because it provides the result to a desired degree of accuracy. However, your simplification is clever an I'll definitely remember it for later use.